# How to Bind Click Listener to Button added from another Activity through Inflater In Android

Tags: android, events

I have been trying to add click listener to a button which I created in an activity but the layout is been added in another activity through Inflater, but the button is not receiving the event below is my code

**XML Layout**

```
 <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_transparent_botton"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                style="@style/transparentButton"
                android:text="Edit Profile"
                android:id="@+id/edit_profile"/>
```

**Main Activity**

```
   public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener{      

    Button edit_profile;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initAddLayout(R.layout.activity_profile);
    setActivityTitle(R.string.profile_activity_title);


    loadData();

    FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(getAssets(), "fonts/Merriweather-Bold.ttf");
    fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content));

    this.edit_profile = findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);
    this.edit_profile.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId()==R.id.edit_profile){
        Log.i("TAG", "PROFILE CLICKED");
    }
  }
}
```

**BaseActivity.class**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
}

  protected void initAddLayout(int layout) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layout, null, false);
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content_below)).addView(view);

}
}
```

the edit_profile button from main activity refuses to accept the click listener.

The essence of extending `BaseActivity` in the `MainActivity` is because `BaseActivity` contains some base functionality that most activities will inherit

The layout for `MainActivity` is been loaded from `BaseActivity` using the `initAddLayout` method of `BaseActivity`

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: What is `view()` doing?

Comment: Please check the update. I have removed `view()` I used it while trying to get it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it as follows:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {   
    protected View profileActivityView;
    ...
    protected void initAddLayout(int layout) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_content_below);
         profileActivityView = inflater.inflate(layout, frameLayout , false);
        frameLayout.addView(profileActivityView);

    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener{      

    Button edit_profile;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initAddLayout(R.layout.activity_profile);
        setActivityTitle(R.string.profile_activity_title);

        ...

        this.edit_profile = profileActivityView.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile);
        this.edit_profile.setOnClickListener(this);
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Please how does `protected View profileActivityView;` gets initialized

Comment: @GhostWorker its initialized in `initAddLayout`

Comment: Thank you @Sagar but the click listener is still not working

Comment: this shows error can not resolve method the second parameter is expected to be a view group

Comment: @GhostWorker I have updated the code. Can you try again? check out `initAddLayout`

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. The problem was coming from my device. The section of the screen where the button is located is not responsive.

Comment: @GhostWorker no problem. Happy to know your problem is solved. Enjoy coding :-)